# IIS 8 - FTP isolation provider - Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: .net, iis-8

I'm trying to add Microsoft.Web.Administration to my VS project as described here:
http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/developing-for-ftp/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-a-simple-ftp-authentication-provider

However Visual Studio keeps telling me that the folder "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\IIS" doesn't exist.

Has anyone had any luck creating custom FTP isolation providers for IIS 8?

Many Thanks,
Ady

Answer (score 0):

you have to use add/remove windows features, and then under FTP server, add the ftp server under IIS, and also the two features inside it (extensibility is one of them). then you get the folder that doesnt exist

Comment: Ok, so to develop for IIS 8, as a developer I need be running windows 8 and have IIS 8 installed on my workstation?

Comment: It says IIS 7.0 or above in the link